# Post Question button not working on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I'm trying to post a question and when clicking on <kbd>Post your question</kbd> it doesn't do anything. I've posted and deleted another question before. Maybe that is not letting me post a new one?

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

[image]

I searched if others had the same problem, but no response explained what was happening to me. I also looked on the console and there are no errors.

Comment: As you said, you don't see any errors in your browser's JavaScript console when you attempt to post the question. What browser, browser version, operating system, and operating system version are you using? Are you using any browser extensions? Any userscripts? It may be helpful for you to include the full, exact text of your attempted question in a code block in your question here, so that other people can attempt to duplicate your problem.

Answer (score 9):

I've searched more and have found that if you have posted once and deleted it, it doesn't allow you to post more for 90 minutes. So waited and tried again being successful.

Comment: was there any error message saying that on the ask question page?

Comment: Nope. No message

Comment: Hmm, according to the [rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/397219) you should have got an error stating *"You can only post once every 90 minutes."*

Comment: Same thing happened to me right now, and also no message. Probably a bug.

Comment: If anyone else is able to reproduce the issue, ping me and I'll add [meta-tag:status-review]

Comment: Only if you promise to disassociate the questions from my sock puppet accounts, @ZoestandswithUkraine . :)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I'm currently having this issue as well with my personal SO account and my work SO account. 

I'm trying to post questions from the same machine, maybe that is hitting the blocker?

Comment: If they are on the same IP then yes you will be rate limited @user1428649 . The rate limit isn't per account, it's per IP (See link in my prior comment).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report!

As you pointed out, there are several validation messages that may stop someone from posting a new question.  However, there was an error that prevented the error popup from displaying, so the action was cancelled without clear communication as to why.

We've restored the error message popup so you should be able to post questions, and if not, should see actionable reasons why like these:

[image: error examples]

Related Issue on MSE: [So many sites won't let me post. How can I fix this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377109/209031)